# Adding a value to a dynamically created element and then having that value pass to another html page when that element is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

The elements are created in a for loop. I have tried storing each element ID in an array but it and using it but its always set to the last value the for loop ran through. Tried solving this problem with closures and still nothing works.

Heres a function I have after for loop, with i being passed in each time. moreinfolink is an empty array initialised outside the for loop. idarr is another array with different values in, which I want to reference using the moreinfolink array. Essentially when each element is clicked, the id it has based on its position in the moreinfolink should be used to then get its relevant position in the idarr, which are passed on to another page. And that pages content is genered using an API, for which we need the correct id (found in the idarr). Hope Im making sense.

```
function passthrough (a){
            
        moreinfolink[a] = document.createElement("a");
        moreinfolink[a].id = a;
        

        newmoreinfo.appendChild(moreinfolink[a]); /* element I created elsewhere */
        moreinfolink[a].innerHTML = "ID position in array is " + moreinfolink[a].id;
        moreinfolink[a].href = "respage.html";

  
        moreinfolink[a].onclick = moreinfo(idarr, moreinfolink[a].id); }
```

Both the overall array of returned ids (idarr) and each links relevant reference id (moreinfolink[a]) is passed into this function below upon the click event. Problem is that the last id is always passed through, so no matter which link you click it always passes through the last id the loop ended with instead of the one that should be assigned to that particular element.

```
function moreinfo (relarr, val) {
var carryover = [];
carryover.push(val);


window.name = carryover;
console.log("carryover is " + carryover)}
```

The function below is called when the other page is opened.

```
function generateapage () {console.log(window.name);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add query stirng to href:

```
moreinfolink[a].href = `/respage&id=${moreinfolink[a].id}`;
```

Then you can read it when other pages load:

```
let id = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('id')
```

Comment: I tried that but the page wouldnt open since I changed the link. Im working with local files in a folder, if that makes a difference.

Comment: No, it doesn't make any difference. Query strings don't change page load behavior. Are you sure you did add it correctly?  BTW, please add your loop and array of ids..

Comment: BTW, why did you add ".html" to href? I edited my answer.

Comment: I added .html because it doesnt open otherwise. I think query strings only work when somethings on a web server, not a local html file.